# Создание страниц в WordPress из сторонней CRM

Tags: wordpress, api

Задача следующая.
Есть CRM https://cleverstaff.net/api.html (вот ее API).
Есть сайт на WordPress.
Нужно, чтобы при создании вакансий в CRM они автоматически добавлялись как страницы на сайт.
Возможно ли это реализовать? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно. Используйте REST API

https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/rest/wp-routes/pages#create-page

Авторизация в REST API

https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/rest/basic/authentication

```
curl -X POST http://адрес_сайта/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?title=Заголовок&slug=my-post&status=publish -H 'Authorization: Basic ключ_авторизации'
```

ключ_авторизации == base64_encode(username:password)

Comment: Где пример с авторизацией? Это не так просто работает

Comment: @WPPunk добавил пример с авторизацией

Comment: А можно хотя бы коротко на примере посмотреть как реализовать?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov в ответе я приложил пример вызова для создания страницы в wordpress